# Powershell method to wait till DOM objects are loaded

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation, webautomation

I am trying to create a powershell script for IE automation. I have created the IE object and navigated to the desired page.

```
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true;
$url="MyURLHERE"
$ie.navigate($url)
```

It asks for windows authentication popup as page is hosted on intranet and once authentication is complete it opens that page. So I have to wait till page is completely loaded (after entering the windows authentication) before executing next statement.
So I used following methods:

```
while($IE.busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
```

But unfortunately once with windows authentication dialog pops up the IE status shows as done. While no DOM object is loaded (Please find below screen shot for status of IE when we get popup for authentication)

[image: Ie status during popup]

So my concern was is there any way to test IE green bar (The one in image) to check status of page load?
I have already tested:

```
readyState <> 4
```

But it didnt work for me. So is there any way to test page loading other than this?

Note: I have work around of testing some string that appears once page is loaded and sleep till it is not present but I am looking for more robust and IE object based approach.

Comment: I think that displaying an authorization request definitely signifies that IE is in a ready state, so you can't check for that to determine whether authorization is passed. I think you should query `$IE.document` data to determine whether it's an authorization request or a 401 or a protected document.

Comment: But why then the green bar of IE is still in loading status?

Comment: Can someone update me I am stuck here. Its more than a month now.